# Updating many json files in Azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, cloud-storage

I have about ~1,000,000 json files, that I would like to update every 30 minutes. The update is simply appending a new array to the end of the existing content.

A single update uses code similar to:

```
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);

            JObject jObject = null;
            // If the blob exists, then we may need to update it.
            if(blockBlob.Exists())
            {
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                blockBlob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);

                jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray())) as JObject;
            } // End of the blob exists

            if(null == jObject)
            {
                jObject = new JObject();
                jObject.Add(new JProperty("identifier", identifier));
            } // End of the blob did not exist

            JArray jsonArray = new JArray();

            jObject.Add(new JProperty(string.Format("entries{0}", timestamp.ToString()),jsonArray));

            foreach(var entry in newEntries)
            {
                jsonArray.Add(new JObject(
                    new JProperty("someId", entry.id),
                    new JProperty("someValue", value)
                    )
                );
            } // End of loop

            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jObject);

            // Upload
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "text/json";
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)));
```

Basically:

1. Check if the blob exists,
2. If it does, download the data and create a json object from the existing details.
3. If it did not, then create a new object with the details.
4. Push the update to the blob.

The problem with this is performance. I've done quite a few things I can do to increase performance (the updates run in five parallel threads and I have set `ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm` to false.

It still runs slow though. Roughly ~100,000 updates can take up to an hour.

So I guess basically, my questions would be:

1. Should I be using Azure Blob storage for this? (I'm open to alternative suggestions).
2. If so, any suggestions on improving performance?

Note: The file basically contains a history of events and I cannot re-generate the entire file based on existing data. This is why the contents are downloaded before being updated.

Comment: How do you use this data?

Comment: I may have it figured out. I'm switching from json to binary format and from `CloudBlockBlob` to `CloudPageBlob`. This allows me to write just the new data to the blob store, without needing to get the previous data first. Working on some timing tests now.

Comment: The problem will come when you try to retrieve the data and create a JSON object out of it. Also page blob works with 512 byte boundary so you may have to pad your data to make it's size a multiple of 512.

Comment: @GauravMantri just reading on that now. The data is ingested by clients (but different data sets per client) and will be processed on the client side, so the format does not really matter (json vs binary).

Comment: If it is incremental updates, you may want to look into Azure Table Storage as well. Each JSON document gets a unique id which could act as `PartitionKey` and then each update is inserted as new row. `RowKey` could be the timestamp (in ticks). Just a thought.

Comment: There are other designs possible, but the right design depends on your scenario. Page blobs, tables, files, or a series of smaller block blobs in a container would all work, each with pros and cons. To help us recommend a better solution, could you clarify:

1. How large does this blob get?
2. How large are the updates? i.e., how many array entries are you appending each time? How often?
3. What is the read pattern? i.e., how do you consume the blob and how often?

Comment: Did you get this to work?  I'm using page blobs at the moment.  I couldn't get the PutBlob method to work so I'm downloading the whole text file, appending the text and then overwritting the whole PageBlog.  This seems inefficient and I'm looking for an easier way.